# Prevent closure in jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, closures

I'm trying to do something that seems (to me, at least) to be a fairly easy, common thing to do.

Here's the HTML for what I've got on a web page:

```
<div class="allergiesDiv">
    <div>
        <span class="editButton">Allergies</span><br />
    </div>
        <span>Allergies</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I turn the first `<span>` into a jQuery button with `$('.editButton').button()`.
(I have many of these pairs on the page.)

What I am *trying* to do is the following:

1. When the button is clicked, it loads a jQuery Dialog with the value of the span that follows it loaded into a `<textarea>`. (BONUS: When the dialog is loaded, I'd like the `<textarea>` to be focused and all text inside highlighted.)
2. The user is able to edit the value and then click 'OK'.
3. When the user clicks 'OK', the Dialog is dismissed and the new value that was entered is used to replace the old value for the span.

Here's the code I'm trying to use (this works OK in IE, but breaks in Mobile Safari and Chrome for PC):

***NOTE: I've been chopping the code up some to try to get each problem isolated. I have had this working, at least in IE.***

```
// How I get the button and bind to the click event
$('.editButton')
    .button({icons: {primary:'ui-icon-pencil'} })
    .click(EditClicked);

// 'Edit' button click handler
function EditClicked() {
    var span = $(this).parent().next().children().first();
    var text = span[0].innerText;
    var dialog = $('<div>').prop('title', 'Edit: ' + $(this).text());
    var textArea = $('<textarea>').css('width', '98%').prop('rows', '4').html(text);
    textArea.appendTo(dialog);

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var buttonTop = $(this).button().offset().top;
    $(dialog).dialog({ 
        modal: true, 
        minWidth: windowWidth / 2, 
        position: ['center',buttonTop], 
        buttons: {
            'Ok' : function () {
                OKClicked(span);
            },
            'Cancel' : function () {
                $(this).dialog('close').remove();
            }
        }
    });
    textArea.focus().select();    
}

// Dialog 'OK' button click handler
function OKClicked(span) {
    var text = $(this).find('textarea')[0].innerText;
    span.html(text);
    $(this).dialog('close').remove(); 
}
```

This is currently broken when it gets to `var buttonTop...`, with the error message of "button is undefined". I haven't yet figured out why that is (I used to have a variable in that method named 'button', but it's gone now. Not sure if that's a caching issue.)

Other than that, can anyone see what's wrong with my **process**? It seems like I've got some kind of misunderstanding with closure, but I'm not yet good enough with JavaScript to understand how to get the kink out of this code.

Comment: Do you have another library included, such as mootools?

Comment: You're missing a `<div>` for the second inner div, aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
var buttonTop = $(this).offset().top;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had at first, but that line kept breaking, so I figured I'd try to see whether the `button()` designation would help. It didn't, and I just haven't removed that bit yet.

Answer (score -1):

1. <strike>I am not sure, that `$('<div>')` is properly syntax for jQuery. Try to use `$('div')` instead.</strike>
2. When you use `$(this).button()` - you try to call `button` method of `$(this)` object. Seems like a bug.

Comment: `$('<div>')` creates an HtmlDivElement, and it is appended it to the DOM afterwards.

Comment: So, it creates `div` element, without closing tag. Are you sure, that all browsers supports it correctly?

Comment: I'm not stating whether or not the the Html is valid, I'm only stating what is happening.  `$('div')` will attempt to locate all divs in the DOM, which is extremely different then creating a new element.